# Alternative to solidus_paypal_braintree for PayPal Payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, spree, solidus, spree-paypal-express

Want to process front-end PayPal payments, directly bypassing Braintree gateway. Can anyone advise or recommend cost for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using - better_solidus_paypal_express!